# Unable to add devices to provisioning portal via Xcode since WWDC

Tags: xcode, ios, enterprise, provisioning, wwdc

I've recently added multiple devices via Xcode Organizer to my provisioning portal, but the devices do not show up in the list of devices when I go into the provisioning portal. The devices also don't receive any of the provisioning profiles that are setup. If I copy the devices UDID number and try to add it manually via the provisioning portal instead of Xcode I get a message saying the device already exists, but as stated above the devices are not listed.  So it appears I have devices sitting in no where land. I can't delete them and I can't view them and I'm unable to add them to any provisioning profiles.

Since I have a enterprise developer license and this is an in-house app I thought I would create a in-house distribution certificate for the app, but when I try to create that I get a message telling me "Unable to process request" please quit your browser and try again or contact apple support. This all just happened this afternoon right after the portal came back up from being down due to WWDC. I'm not sure if that has anything to do with it, but any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Someone else just posted a similar question, so it's probably an Apple thing (server flooded since WWDC if i had to guess), I would try contacting them.

Comment: Indeed probably an Apple problem. My access to the developers forums was also canned (can only access Safari and WWDC ones).